# select dropdown list - wrong characters

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've a simple select element on my website wich displays strange characters on the dropdown list :

[image: strange dropdown]

I'm using BootFlat to create the ui and the select is inside a `<td>` element. It works just fine on Firefox but not on Chrome and Opera. I've already search but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

I thought it was an encoding issue but even when I change the browser encoding, the problem remains. (the meta and the file html are both set in utf-8).

Here's the code and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Carvallegro/ybpfH/) from my page :

```
<td>
  <select>
     <option value="Travail">Travail</option>
     <option value="Congés">Conges</option>
     <option value="Absence">Absence</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: JSfiddle please. What font is being used?

Comment: Looks like somewhere along the way the options are getting a new font.  A fiddle will insure it is reproducible, but look into your stylesheets as to what option: font-family is being set to.

Comment: I'm using Lato font, JSFiddle is coming, i'm working on it (first time using it)

Comment: Does the JSFiddle not work? It works on Safari

Comment: Well it works perfectly, even on Chrome and Opera...

Comment: But I'm assuming it doesn't work on your local machine. Can we have a look at your website?

Comment: Exactly ! And i've checked on the Chrome Console if the font changed somewhere but no. And even when I force the Lato font on the select, it doesn't work (I still have strange characters, but in Lato)